# Active Reports - C# Creating Page Header Column Name based on table values

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, activereports

I want create a report that contains 3 product group based on need to create page header column name (ie.) Product group Name, have to be loaded from the table in MS SQL 2008. In Detail section we need to show data based on colunm name (Product Name). Guys i am new to Activereports sorry this may be basic questions. Your helps are highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If working with PageReports, you may create groups by fields or expressions in a [dataregion](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/GrapeCity.ActiveReports.v7%7EGrapeCity.ActiveReports.PageReportModel.DataRegion.html). And depending on the dataregion you select, the data can be grouped in various ways. For detailed information on these ways please refer to [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/GroupingDataPageLayout.html) documentation link.

In order to get further information on binding, you may follow [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/ConnecttoaDataSource.html) link.
Various walkthroughs and samples can be found at [this](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/Samples%20and%20Walkthroughs.html) location.

Regards,
Mohita